# Touch not registered near a triangle (Box2D)?

Tags: android, touch, box2d, andengine

I'm using AndEngine/Box2D to develop a game on the Android OS. When the user touches the screen, it creates a triangle using the triangle example:

```
private static Body createTriangleBody(final PhysicsWorld pPhysicsWorld, final IAreaShape pAreaShape, final BodyType pBodyType, final FixtureDef pFixtureDef) {
    /* Remember that the vertices are relative to the center-coordinates of the Shape. */
    final float halfWidth = pAreaShape.getWidthScaled() * 0.5f / PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT;
    final float halfHeight = pAreaShape.getHeightScaled() * 0.5f / PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT;

    final float top = -halfHeight;
    final float bottom = halfHeight;
    final float left = -halfHeight;
    final float centerX = 0;
    final float right = halfWidth;

    final Vector2[] vertices = {
            new Vector2(centerX, top),
            new Vector2(right, bottom),
            new Vector2(left, bottom)
    };

    return PhysicsFactory.createPolygonBody(pPhysicsWorld, pAreaShape, vertices, pBodyType, pFixtureDef);
}
```

However, a touch near the triangle is not registered (as I discovered using a Log), meaning you fill up the screen with useable triangles pretty quickly. The blue is the triangle, the red is where a touch isn't registered:

[image]

Any ideas why a touch isn't registered within these bounds?

Here is another diagram:
[image]

So the scene may end up looking something like this. As the user presses and holds, the triangle increases in size. When the user lifts his finger, the triangle stops growing and falls to the bottom of the screen. Even though the original triangle is roughly the size of the red triangle, touches are not registered in the areas marked with an 'X'.

Answer (score 0):

Touch on objects is detected using OnAreaTouchListener, touch outside objects is detected using OnSceneTouchListener - this is the one you need to use to detect touch within the red area.

Comment: Yes... By running a Log statement in OnSceneTouchListener, a touch is not registered in the red area, which is technically outside the bounds of the triangle. I was wondering if there was something to do with fixtures creating a rectangle around the texture region or something.

Comment: So the red area is not registered by either OnSceneTouchListener or OnAreaTouchListener? It shouldn't have anything to do with fixtures, the touch handling is part of AndEngine.

Comment: Correct, neither registers. I had this same kind of problem before when I removed a body but didn't unregister the touch area. In that same situation, neither touch registered either. But I'm not removing anything here.

Comment: One thing that comes to mind is that the touch handling for primitive shapes might be implemented in a stupid way that registers touch area of a rectangle and then ignores the parts of it that are not within the triangle. But Nicolas Gramlich, the author of AndEngine, is surely not stupid and would not implement it that way, right? Another possibility is that you are creating the polygon in a wrong direction. I think I have heard that one must create them counter-clockwise, so try swapping Vector2(right, bottom) with Vector2(left, bottom). That could help.

Comment: Unfortunately, changing the order did not fix the problem.